# Php sheet looks different when trying to print?

Tags: php, css, printing

I used a Css stylesheet to put my textboxes in the right position, in crome the txtbox and the sentence looks fine, everything is in the right place but when trying to print the site using ctrl+p every sentence and every textbox moves, what can I do so it looks the same?:

```
<!--
#caption_1 {
position:relative;
left:-120px;
top:0px;
width:175px;
height:22px;
font-size:18px;

}
-->

<!--
#txtfeld_1 {
    position:relative;
    left:-100px;
    top:0px;
      width:175px;
    height:22px;
    font:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:center;  
}
-->
```

Also here my textbox example:

```
print '<font size="4" id="caption_1" face="Calibri">Absender Typ / Shipper type:</font></div><input type="text" name="absenderTyp" value="'.$absenderTyp.'" id="txtfeld_1" readonly></div>';
```

Comment: use @media print to define css for printing only and/or force to maintain positions. Some stuff is discarded by the browser by default when it's preparing to print.

Comment: while using media print, the txtboxes change their position, do I have to align them new and then print?

Comment: copy your normal css into a @media print block, that should be enough to get a "same placement" thing, but some other stuff (like container width) may change that, so try to be as explicit as posible

Comment: never used media: so should I just put @media print {
  ***Here all my other css blocks?***
} And change the incluse to media="print"?

Comment: you already have a css file being included, don't specify the media. then do `@media print { *copy of all your other css blocks or the ones you want to work the same in the printed version* }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have something like this:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>
```

and a styles.css file like this:

```
#caption_1 {
    position:relative;
    left:-120px;
    top:0px;
    width:175px;
    height:22px;
    font-size:18px;
}
#txtfeld_1 {
    position:relative;
    left:-100px;
    top:0px;
      width:175px;
    height:22px;
    font:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:center;  
}
```

right below add:

```
@media print {
    #caption_1 {
        position:relative;
        left:-120px;
        top:0px;
        width:175px;
        height:22px;
        font-size:18px;
    }
    #txtfeld_1 {
        position:relative;
        left:-100px;
        top:0px;
          width:175px;
        height:22px;
        font:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:12px;
        text-align:center;  
    }
}
```

that should force the browser to use those same styles on the printed version of your page, giving you (more or less) the same result as your "screen" version.

Bear in mind that some stuff like the page width wich is usually expressed in percentage of screen will now be calculated over the page width instead, but from the css you posted, you're using static measurements.

Comment: Ok it worked a bit at least, now I can move them with "left: ..." but the site looks always the same, then I change the position of a textfield it looks the same on the site but different in the print pop up.

Comment: you need to redo changes into the media print block to affect the printable version and into the normal block for the normal screen version.

Comment: Ok thx it worked, but not perfekt, if I try to print the site it looks the same in the print pop up, but I just saw now the window gets smaller when printing so the text on the left it cut out a litte, and if I try to change just the printing option so just #caption_1 inside the @media print nothing happens

Comment: You meant that you moved the "left:-120px" to a lower value (like -140 or so) to compensate?